# SwiftUI fill shape with a custom pattern

Tags: swiftui

I would like to use .fill modifier to fill a Shape with a pattern, for example, a checked pattern.

I have for example

```
Rectangle()
   .fill(Color.red)
```

I know I can use something like

```
let myGradient = LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.black, . red]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)

 .fill(myGradient)
```

But I cannot get any of the gradients to create the pattern I am after

I see that *fill* needs to conform to *ShapeStyle*, is there an example of how I could create my own *ShapeStyle*

[image]

I do **not** want to create a custom shape only a custom fill

Comment: Try this article [on filling with `ImagePaint`](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/creative-borders-and-fills-using-imagepaint) if you don't mind using an image as the pattern.